# Associate IP addresses with countries

Tags: geolocation, ip-address, geoip

I want to show country flag depending on ip address I receive at server side.
Are fixed ip addresses are assigned to countries ? Where can I get database for ip address to country mapping ?

Comment: Quite straight forward. Get [country flag icons](http://365icon.com/icon-styles/ethnic/classic2/) & map [IP address to country](https://ipapi.co/api/?shell#specific-field-for-an-ip) name. The icon & country names are linked via country [codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

- [IP address geolocation SQL database](http://www.iplocationtools.com/sql_database.php)
- [Geo Locate IP Address XML API Whois Map Country Provider](http://www.infosniper.net/geolocate-ip-addresses-api.php)
- [How to Geolocate Visitors Using an IP-to-Country Database](http://www.ardamis.com/2008/01/27/how-to-geolocate-visitors-using-an-ip-to-country-database/)
- [Free IP to Country Database](http://software77.net/geo-ip/)
- [My IP Address Lookup and Geotarget IP Project](http://www.hostip.info/)
- [MaxMind - Open Source IP Address to Country Database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country)
- [IP address geolocation SQL database](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php)

Also on Stack Overflow:

- [What is the most applicable solution to detect which country an ip belongs to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451442/what-is-the-most-applicable-solution-to-detect-which-country-an-ip-belongs-to)
- [Is there any possible way to find the name of the country using IP with scripting language PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543437/is-there-any-possible-way-to-find-the-name-of-the-country-using-ip-with-scripting)
- [IP to Country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country)
- [code for finding the state,country,city from the IP Adress in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806842/code-for-finding-the-state-country-city-from-the-ip-adress-in-php)

Once you have the country code, then you can display the flag with these free icon sets which use ISO country codes:

- [Flag icons](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/)
- [Flags of the World](http://flags.blogpotato.de/)

PHP Advent also just published a whole article on a very similar process:

- [GeoIP Wrangling](http://phpadvent.org/2009/geoip-wrangling-by-andrei-zmievski)

Comment: It would be nice to know which resource/link you used to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for an [IP geolocation](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&hs=nF0&q=IP+geolocation&btnG=Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=) service such as [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/).

Comment: Or GeoBytes (http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation), or... We should all probably just edit this answer (which is, generically, use a reference site) with a list of them. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is not showing exact location. Shown some other.

Comment: @udaykiranpulipati: These things are imperfect.

Answer (score 1):

**ip2location.com** provides an IP range database which can be used to tag IP addresses

*they provide it in different formats as well so you can choose which one is useful to you*

Answer (score 1):

Maxmind is the one we use

Answer (score 0):

Open Sourced self contained flag rendering based on IP:
[ip2ensign](https://github.com/stolk/ip2ensign)

It will lookup UV coordinates in a flag texture atlas that matches an arbitrary IP.
And it comes with the IP range database and the texture.