# Country name in codeigniter url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

My question is how to append country name in codeigniter url?

Lets say my website is http://mywebsite.com and I am opening the website from Canada so my url should be http://mywebsite.com/canada.
Meaning I just want to append the country name in the url, nothing change except this. I have read about routes of codeigniter, I have googled it but all in vain.

If anyone have  a clue how to do this please let me know.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this unless you are serving separate content for different countries? You should explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd do that with a IP lookup to guess the country based on the request IP address ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']). Mapping the IP address to a location is [pretty well documented.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935621/associate-ip-addresses-with-countries) Once you have the country, redirect to the correct controller method.

That what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is like for language code in url.

With my solution you can put any segment in your uri and hide it to CI.

http://site.com/page.html will be equal to http://site.com/canada/page.html and vice versa.

set_country_uri.php

```
//App location
$ci_directory = '/ci/';

//countries
$countries = array('canada','france');

//default country
$country = 'canada';

foreach( $countries as $c )
{
    if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $ci_directory.$c)===0)
    {
        //Store country founded
        $country = $c;

        //Delete country from URI, codeigniter will don't know is exists !
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr_replace($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '', strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'.$c)+1, strlen($c)+1);

        break;
    }
}

//Add the country in URI, for site_url() function
$assign_to_config['index_page'] = $country."/";

//store country founded, to be able access it in your app
define('COUNTRY', $country);
```

index.php

```
<?php

require('set_country_uri.php');

//ci code ...
```

So in your CI code use `COUNTRY` constant to know wich is used. And make your code like routing without take in consideration the country in the uri.